# Choosing potential function in amortized analysis

Tags: algorithm-analysis, amortized-analysis

How should I think to choose the potential function in the amortized analysis?
More specifically are there techniques or tips for choosing optimal or good potential functions?

Comment: This is a very general question, but one that definitely makes sense. Are there techniques for choosing optimal or good potential functions? Is there a nice list of examples? How does this method related to another techniques for amortized analysis?

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: Why the down-votes? This is a legitimate question, similar to some of our reference questions.

Comment: Don't [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32867/how-can-i-make-sense-of-amortized-accounting-method) and [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30543/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-potential-function-in-amortized-analysis-of-som) question answer yours? Note that the answer here is likely "choose it so that the calculations go through" with some vague, example-driven intuitions. It's a creative thing. (Other than most of the other general reference questions, btw, @YuvalFilmus).

Comment: @Raphael That's exactly the point – for all we know there *are* some general techniques here. I am just not aware of any, but if somebody else is, I think it would be interesting and useful.